# Count published posts for a category and month/year

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I would like to count published posts for a category and month/year but I can not...

I can do for a category (without set month/year) :

```
SELECT wp_term_taxonomy.count
FROM wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy
WHERE wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id=7
```

but not with month/year :

```
SELECT count
FROM wp_term_taxonomy, wp_posts, wp_term_relationships
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
  AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
  AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '7'
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND wp_posts.post_date LIKE '2011-06-%'
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think it's good with :

SELECT COUNT( * )
FROM wp_term_taxonomy, wp_posts, wp_term_relationships
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '7'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_posts.post_date LIKE '2011-06-%'

:D

Comment: LIKE works only with strings, not dates

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM wp_term_taxonomy, wp_posts, wp_term_relationships 
WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id 
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = '7' 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 

AND YEAR(wp_posts.post_date) =2011
AND MONTH(wp_posts.post_date) =6
```

Or replace the last two lines with between

```
AND wp_posts.post_date BETWEEN '2011-06-01' AND '2011-06-30'
```

Comment: ...or just `AND DATE_FORMAT(wp_posts.post_date, '%Y%m') = '201106'`

Comment: Thanks, it's similary to what i've post :)